# How to create 3D our office building with same architecture and design in City Engine

Tags: arcgis-pro, cityengine

How we can create 3D of our office building with the same architecture and design in City Engine.

I have a 2D footprint of our office building,and i want to convert into 3D design in same architecture.

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to state what you have tried, and where you are stuck.